# Is there a way to automatically include the console output with the crash log on ios

Tags: iphone, debugging, ios, ipod-touch, crash-dumps

The crash log returned when your app has an error on iOS is wonderful however it would be 100 times better if it contained the console output from when your app started as part of the log. Is there a way to automatically have that information in the crash log, or have a semi-automatic system that testers could use when sending in crash logs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might want to take a look at http://apphance.com. It's exactly what you are looking for - including capability of sending problem reports from device by testers, including screenshots, you can track history of session including full console logs, you can even see crashes from out-of-memory problems which are otherwise difficult to get without physical access to the device. It's closed beta for now but soon it will be open for everyone. You can request access directly at the page.

Disclaimer: I am CTO of Polidea, company which is behind apphance and co-creator of the service.

Comment: this sounds pretty good, I was hoping for something that could be done without a third party tool. But I'll give you the answer since there doesnt seem to be another way.

Answer (score 0):

@Medran i am not sure if this will help but if you can get the Brad Larsons videos on Advance iPhone App Development than there he says some thing about `.dSYM` file that will help you find the places where crash occurs. `.dSYM` file is made when you build your app using Xcode. See if you can find that file in your project folder its named something like this `MYapp.app.dSYM`

Comment: @Medran was asking about how to retrieve run-time crash info, while you were talking about the dSYM file. Though dSYM file was related to symbolicating the crash log. It was not related to getting the crash log in the first place.

Comment: @diwup i said that i not sure about this at the start of my answer.which means i was not sure about it.

Comment: ya I don't think the dSYM is going to cut it for this problem, but thanks for trying. I'm almost feeling like I need some sort of master exception handler that can save a customized crash log that contains the console output, and upload to our servers(development builds only). I wouldn't mind watching that video though do you know the Name of the video under itunes?