# Is there a way to include an error description string in a crash report?

Tags: iphone, ios, crash-reports

Is there a way to include an error description string in a crash report? I'm talking about crash reports that are sent via iTunes Connect. It would be nice if I could log the reason for a crash.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941359/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-include-the-console-output-with-the-crash-log-on) asks about including console output, but I'd be happy just to able to include an error description string, without resorting to a 3rd party library.

**EDIT:**

There are errors I can detect where it's unwise or impossible to attempt to recover, because the program is probably in a corrupt state. I'd rather not catch these exceptions so that I get automatic error reporting with a stack trace. Sometimes, there is extra information that I'd like to log (that cannot be deduced from the stack trace), such as the current state of a state machine.

Comment: If you know why you're crashing, why not just fix it? I don't get how you expect to annotate a crash. (Especially since many of those I've seen are actually your app being killed by the watchdog timer.)

Comment: A crash can be caused by a failed assertion or an uncaught exception. These will generate crash reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched and searched. There seems to no way to annotate a pending crash report. If someone comes up with an answer, I'll change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about a third party crash reporter? I've integrated [QuincyKit](http://quincykit.net/), and even found a way to [annotate them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588474/quincykit-plcrashreporter-provide-description-before-the-crash).

Also, when the app actively begs for the crash report to be sent to the support, you get much more of them. The things you learn...

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out for my next project.