# Low-level shared memory on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, ipc, shared-memory

I'm trying to construct a block of shared memory on iOS. It compiles and links, but `shmget()` throws a SIGSYS signal on the most innocent parameters:

```
NSString *p = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"crash" ofType: nil];
key_t tok = ftok([p UTF8String], 918273);
int mid = shmget(tok, 4096, IPC_CREAT|S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
```

`tok` is a large positive integer, not -1. Size - tried 1024, same effect.

Is SysV shared memory even supported on iOS? The headers and the libraries are present, or compiler/linker would complain. Same code works on the simulator. What am I doing wrong?

My interest stems from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588474/quincykit-plcrashreporter-provide-description-before-the-crash).

Comment: I still can't work out why you feel the need to use shared memory on a system that doesn't properly support multitasking.

Comment: Want a storage that a) persists beyond process shutdown b) does not need to persist beyong device restart c) is fast and cheap d) is on the order of 1KB. Found some workarounds, but shared memory would be the cheapest of them all, if it worked.

Comment: Persisting across app shutdown but not device shutdown seems wrong. Device restart should be transparent to apps...

Comment: It's more normal to use NSUserDefaults, but a `mmap()`ed file probably would be similar to SHM, depending on how often the kernel schedules writeback.

Comment: @R..: tell that to the clipboard. By the way, private named UIPasteboard is one of the workarounds I found...

Comment: Why should the clipboard be lost if the device powers down? That's annoying. What if you drop your phone or accidentally let the battery run down while it has something important you want to paste? The clipboard contents should still be there when you get power back. This is basic common-sense interface design with the principle of least surprise...

Comment: @JensGustedt: It's Objective C, which unlike C++ is basically just a preprocessor and runtime environment on top of C, and which thankfully seems to be aligned with the underlying C standard.

Comment: My app is in Objective C++, but that's irrelevant to the question. The SysV shared memory mechanism is completely C friendly, predates object oriented programming as a concept, and is sometimes (incorrectly) considered "a part" of the *nix flavor of C.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev, then either tag your question correctly or "translate" your example to C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `shm_open()/mmap()` combo works as advertised, both on simulator and on device (tested on iOS 4) without any explicit permission changes.

Note: `shm_open()` is weirdly documented as variadic. In reality, you need to specify a third parameter with an access mask - a combination of `S_IRUSR`-like flags, or an octal `chmod` value.

EDIT: looks like it broke in iOS 7. shm_open returns -1 with errno=2 (ENOENT) even though O_CREAT flag is specified.

Comment: Hi Seva do you have any samples or documents how to implement it

Answer (score 1):

On iOS you cannot use shared memory at all
I don't know the exact details but I do know that a) its for security and b) its part of the sandboxing environment

So I know above from myself and my presence in the jailbreak scene however here are a few links describing sandboxing and how they affect shared memory

http://www.trailofbits.com/resources/ios4_security_evaluation_paper.pdf

http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2012/Apr/msg00535.html

Comment: The cited article states the opposite: "The “container” sandbox profile is the profile that gets applied to all third-party applications. (...) Finally, the profile `does not` restrict actions related to POSIX semaphores, shared memory, file IOCTLs, Mach bootstrap servers, network socket binding and accepting inbound connections, certain classes of privileged actions, and reading kernel state information through the kernel sysctl interface." The linked forum post just restates the problem. Sorry, no accept for you.

Comment: right, if you read further, it doesnt restrict it if you /add/ the permission to the entitlements file, however on idevice those entitlements do not work (at least in my experience)

Comment: the best i can get other than that is this: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/mDNSResponder/mDNSResponder-320.5/mDNSMacOSX/mDNSResponder.sb?txt an actual example of it being used

Comment: That's system code, I believe. They get different permissions than the third party sandbox.