# Is NSTemporaryDirectory in RAM?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Does anyone know if the directory that `NSTemporaryDirectory()` returns on iOS is temporary in the *nix sense - as in in-memory `tmpfs`?

I'm looking for workarounds around [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589105/shmget-throws-sigsys-on-ios).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not. It is a temporary directory in the sense that it's content is periodically erased (every 3 days or so I think). The folder itself is physical on the storage and is somewhere in your app's sandbox.