# Ashmem retention policy

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, shared-memory, ashmem

So on Android there's neither POSIX shared memory nor SysV shared memory, but there's `ashmem`. I want to use it to collect some postmortem info from crashes in the native subsystem (like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588474/quincykit-plcrashreporter-provide-description-before-the-crash)). Question - can I make an ashmem region persist when the process that holds the handle to them dies? Where's ashmem documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's no builtin way to make a region stick. So I've built an out-of-process service, I pass a descriptor to a region to it, and hope the service outlives the main process. There's no lifetime guarantee for background services on Android, as everyone knows.

The service has a static variable of type `ParcelFileDescriptor` and supports two binder commands - GET and SET. They, respectively, return the said descriptor in the response parcel and assign it from the request parcel, closing the currently held one (if any).